# Symfony2 route in annotations with optional parameters

Tags: symfony, annotations, router

i created a route with optional parameter in controller like this:

```
/**
 * League action
 *
 * @Route("/association/{assoc}/{league}", name="league", requirements={"league" = "\d+"}, defaults={"game" = null})
 * @Route("/association/{assoc}/{league}/{game}")
 * @Template()
 *
 * @param $assoc
 * @param $league
 * @param $game
 * @return array
 */
 public function leagueAction($assoc, $league, $game)
```

but if i try to create a link with this named route, the optional parameter is ommitted:

```
{{ path('league', {'assoc': association.short, 'league': league.id, 'game': g.id}) }}
```

resulting link is

> /association/BVNR/7

What am i missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the following definitions,

```
* @Route("/association/{assoc}/{league}", name="league", requirements={"league" = "\d+"}, defaults={"game" = null})
* @Route("/association/{assoc}/{league}/{game}")
```

two routes are related to your action, the first one (named `"league"` which doesn't have any default parameter and a second unnamed one (as you didn't add name attribute) which also doesn't have any default parameter.

**How to fix ...**

- Add a `name` to your second route and call it as it contains `"game"` parameter.
- Move the default value of `"game"` parameter to your second route (As it the only one to have a `game` parameter.
- (You don't really need to define two routes, take a look at the `"How to improve ..."` part of my answer).

**Try this ...**

```
 * @Route("/association/{assoc}/{league}/{game}", name="league_game", requirements={"league" = "\d+"}, defaults={"game" = null})
```

While you should call `"league_game"` instead of `"league"`,

```
{{ path('league_game', {'assoc': association.short, 'league': league.id, 'game': g.id}) }}
```

**How to improve ...**

Make sure you really need to define two routes, because I would suggest keeping only one route.

As there's a default value for `"game"`in the following definition,

```
@Route("/association/{assoc}/{league}/{game}", name="league", requirements={"league" = "\d+"}, defaults={"game" = null}
```

It then covers both versions, with and without `"game"`.

Comment: ah - naming second route did the trick. But i have to use defaults also with first route, as symfony claims about required parameter game.
So this seems to work:
    * @Route("/association/{assoc}/{league}", name="league", requirements={"league" = "\d+"}, defaults={"game" = null})
    * @Route("/association/{assoc}/{league}/{game}", name="leaguedetails", defaults={"game" = null})

Comment: ommitting first route doesn't work, i tried all combinations.

Comment: You don't need to define "game" as a default parameter to your first route as it didn't contain any "game" parameter.
Then, your first route should be called as follow: 
{{ path('league', {'assoc': association.short, 'league': league.id}) }} where league.id must fit the "\d+" constraint.

Comment: Ahmed - if i ommit defaults on first route, i get following error:

Controller "...\LigaController::leagueAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$game" argument (because there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument after this one). 

though in link generating for first route i don't use parameter game.

Comment: Ah sorry, you're right, I didn't see your action signature. You need to set a value (default or not) for all the parameters used by leagueAction.

Comment: ah, ok - need to change function parameter to optional, then i can ommit defaults on first route:
public function leagueAction($assoc, $league, $game = null)

Comment: Exactly! As it's (well) explained [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#route-parameters-controller-arguments).

Comment: btw, you don't need two route definitions. Because only `game` is optional, one defintion is enough: `@Route("/association/{assoc}/{league}/{game}", name="league", requirements={"league" = "\d+"}, defaults={"game" = null})`. Generate both versions with or without game parameter trough the `league` route.

Comment: Yeah, sure. As suggested in the "Also ..." part of my answer. Thanks for making it clearer.

Comment: Jep, maybe it would be worth an edit, to make this clear. Especially for other users, which are searching on similar issue, that only one route is enough.