# What does the @param keyword do in symfony routes

Tags: php, annotations, symfony, symfony-routing

In annotations for a route what does @param mean?

I can not find any documentation on symfony website regarding this keyword and very confused as to what it's for and does.

I'm asking because I'm trying to figure out how to access parameters in my .yml files for use in the routes but I'd like to still use annotations instead of the YML method of routing.

Showing a code example is probably not the best for this but here is where @param shows up

```
/**
 * League action
 *
 * @Route("/association/{assoc}/{league}", name="league", requirements={"league" = "\d+"}, defaults={"game" = null})
 * @Route("/association/{assoc}/{league}/{game}")
 * @Template()
 *
 * @param $assoc
 * @param $league
 * @param $game
 * @return array
 */
```

I took that from here ([Symfony2 route in annotations with optional parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18694107/symfony2-route-in-annotations-with-optional-parameters))

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: why negative votes for this question? I legitimately could not find resources for what it meant/was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@param` and `@return` are [phpDocumentor annotations](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/guides/docblocks.html), and do not actually affect routing.

Comment: ah I see, was wondering what it was for.  Now I know its not what I thought it was.